# How can I display 2 images next to each other but only display one on hover?

Tags: html, css

I have a giant list of images currently in an unordered list and i'm now trying to alter it to display another image over the original *only* when hovered and in process of that, hide the original image.

I can almost get it to work with the below code but it's only hiding the original picture and not bringing the new picture into view.

```css
.mainImg {
  opacity: 1;
}

.mainImg:hover {
  opacity: 0;
}

.hidgeImg {
  display: none;
}

.hideImg:hover {
  display: inline-block;
}

<!-- dont know if the picture CSS is relevant but here it is -->
#pictures li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 33%;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

#pictures img {
  vertial-align: top;
  max-height: 350px;
}
```

```html
<ul id="pictures">
  <li>
    <a href="/"><img src="image1.jpg" class="mainImg">
      <img src="image2.jpg" class="hideImg">
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I have commented the code where it is relevant to you.**

You were very close, what needs to happen is you need a parent element that, when hovered over, will handle the hovering events for each of its parent images.
If you remove the ability to see `mainImg` on hover for example, then there is no element to be hovering over that makes `hideImg` display.
If you have a parent object to hover over, that is always 'displayed' (but never has any visual other than its child img) then you can handle hover events via thisparent.

This is down by specifying what is being hovered over, followed by the query/selector of the element you want to change (**E.G** `.parent:hover .child{CSS HERE;}`)

```html
<head>
  <style>
  //When parent is hovered voer, make main hidden and hideen displayed
  #hoverelement:hover .hideImg{
    display: inline-block;
  }
  #hoverelement:hover .mainImg{
    display: none;
  }
  //Hide Img is hidden by default
  .hideImg{
    display: none;
  }

  <!-- dont know if the picture CSS is relevant but here it is -->
  li {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 33%;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: center;
  }
  img {
    vertial-align: top;
    max-height: 350px;
  }
  #MainArea{
    background-color:tan;
    padding:5%;
  }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="MainArea">
      <ul id="pictures">
      <li>
        <a href="/" id="hoverelement"><!--Add a parent element to handle hovering -->
          <img src="https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/arctichare.png" class="mainImg">
          <img src="https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/airplane.png" class="hideImg">
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul> 
  </div>
</body>

CSS
```

Comment: ah thank you so much! I was thinking that was the problem, once the image is hidden, there's nothing to hover over it to bring the second image into view. Just couldn't think how to solve that. This did it though. Thank you again!

Comment: @WeyersdeLange You place the Images 'Next' to each other in a parent dv. But since only one will be displayed at a time, there will only ever be one image at the left-most location.